# Reorganize array of arrays to array of hashes and convert to JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following  array

```
var arr=[[10,20,30],[12,21,33],[13,23,35]];
```

How can I convert that array to JSON.
Desired result

`myJSONarr=[
              {"x":10 ,"y":20,"z":30},
              {"x":12 ,"y":21,"z":33},
              {"x":13, "y":23,"z":35}
               ];`

I'm guessing I will have to define sting  array

```
var objArray=["x","y","z"];
```

and do loop over these two values with the `eval()` function. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use jquery:

```
var arr=[[10,20,30],[12,21,33],[13,23,35]],
myjson = JSON.stringify($.map(arr,function(a){return {x:a[0],y:a[1],z:a[2]}}));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/herostwist/yDRwh/

if you use prototype:

```
var myjson  = JSON.stringify([[10,20,30],[12,21,33],[13,23,35]].map(function(a){
              return {x:a[0],y:a[1],z:a[2]}}));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/herostwist/yDRwh/1/

Comment: @user711522: Only use it if you use jQuery anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want to map the values to JavaScript objects<sup>†</sup>:

```
var objs = [];

for(var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
    var p = arr[i];
    objs.push({x: p[0], y: p[1], z: p[2]});
}
```

If you really want to create a JSON string, then you can pass this array to [**`JSON.stringify`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_JSON_in_Firefox). `JSON` is available in all modern browser [and can be loaded for older ones](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).

---

†: Why am I assuming here? Because people confuse JSON with JavaScript object literals. In your code, `myJSONarr` is **not** JSON. It is an array of JS objects. It would be JSON if the data would be contained in a string:

```
var myJSONarr = '[{"x":10, "y":20, "z":30}, ...]';
```

**`JSON != JavaScript object`**

Answer (score 0):

My version. Edit: I didn't twig objArray wasn't part of the problem, but the OP's suggestion as part of the solution. Oh well, I like it anyway.

```
var arr=[[10,20,30],[12,21,33],[13,23,35]];    
var objArray=["x","y","z"];

var myJSONarr = [];

for (var idx = 0; idx != arr.length; idx++) {
    var row = {};
    for (var idx2 = 0; idx2 != objArray.length; idx2++) {
       row[objArray[idx2]] = arr[idx][idx2];
    }
    myJSONarr.push(row);
}

alert(JSON.stringify(myJSONarr));
```

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
var arr = [[10,20,30], [12,21,33], [13,23,35]];

var arr2 = [];
for (var i in arr) {
    var a = arr[i];
    arr2.push({
        x: a[0],
        y: a[1],  
        z: a[2]
    });
}
```

Or, using higher-order functions:

```
var labels = ["x", "y", "z"];
var arr = [[10,20,30], [12,21,33], [13,23,35]];
var arr2 = arr.map(function(a) {
    return a.reduce(function(prev, curr, i) {
        prev[labels[i]] = curr;
        return prev;
    }, {});
});
```

Then directly convert the new array to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Many different answers, here's another:

http://jsfiddle.net/Vecqc/

```
<textarea id="text" style="width: 100%;"></textarea>

var arr = [[10,20,30],[12,21,33],[13,23,35]];
var stringify = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    stringify[i] = {'x':arr[i][0],'y':arr[i][0],'z':arr[i][0]};
}

document.getElementById('text').value = JSON.stringify(stringify);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is not merely a JSON conversion.  You actually have an array full of three element arrays of numbers, and what you are wanting is JSON for an array of hashes where each triplet becomes a hash over "x","y","z".

Anyway, if you want a simple .toJSON() function, Prototype.js includes a .toJSON() function onto most objects that makes it really easy.

http://www.prototypejs.org/learn/json

Untested...

```
var arr=[[10,20,30],[12,21,33],[13,23,35]];
var myarrOfXYZ = arr.collect(function(T){ return $H({ x: T[0], y: T[1], z: T[2] }) });
var myJSON = myarrOfXYZ.toJSON();
```

Note that prototype also provides a function "zip" that can be used on line 2 instead of $H

Comment: Thank you. I haven't tried the prototype approach yet. I intend to try all  the solution provided here. I am new to JS .

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through the array and create a string from each array inside it, then join the strings to form the JSON string:

```
var items = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  items.push('{"x":'+arr[i][0]+',"y":'+arr[i][1]+',"z":'+arr[i][2]+'}');
}
var myJSONarr = '[' + items.join(',') + ']';
```

Comment: @Felix Kling: Why not? It's a very simple format. And the code works with any browser version, not only the ones released after JSON was introduced.